# How to enable 'Go' button on virtual keyboard in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, tablet, smartphone, virtual-keyboard

I am a newbie to javascript and am currently building a website with a form that navigates users to a different page if they enter the correct code into a form and press the 'Submit' button.

Currently users have to click the 'Submit' button on the page in order for it to work — they can't use the 'Go' button on virtual keyboard on devices like tablets or iPhones at the moment. I want to fix the site so that users can also use the 'Go' button on their tablets and smartphones as an alternative to having to click the 'Submit' button'.

My code:

The button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-large span12" id="joe_btn" onclick="onSubmit()" touchstart="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
```

The Javascript that runs it:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function onSubmit() {
                 if (document.getElementById('password').value == '03010213') {window.location.href = 'map.html'; }
                  else{ alert('Please check your passcode and try again');}
                       }
  </script>
```

How do I fix the code so that users can use the 'Go' button on their tablets and smartphones and it works as well?

Any feedback would be gratefully recieved! Please note, I am a complete beginner with Javascript, so please show the exact corrected code in your answers that I would need to use.

Many thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in order for the `Go` button to show up, you need an `input type="submit"` on the page. On click of that button, run your function and return false. An actual form submit will not go through, as your script will take you to a different URL. Note that the inputs need to be part of a `form` as shown in the answer and in the fiddle. Here is a JSFiddle showing it working: http://jsfiddle.net/3TG6w/3/embedded/result - browse to this on your mobile device.

```
<form method="post" action="home.html">
  <input type="password" id="password"/>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-large span12" id="joe_btn" onclick="onSubmit(); return false;" touchstart="onSubmit(); return false;" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementById('password').value == '03010213') {window.location.href = 'map.html';
    }
    else{
        alert('Please check your passcode and try again');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I was slightly off in my original answer. Check out the JSFiddle on an iOS device to show the 'Go' button and the code working as expected.